# Stop announcement of who is calling me

Tags: notifications

How do I stop my phone from announcing the name of who is calling me on my Droid Razr Maxx? I've gone into my settings and can't find out why this is doing this.

Comment: See if my answer works. If not, let me know. If it does, you know what to do. :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have Driving Mode enabled. In my Samsung Galaxy S4, it's in `Settings > My device > Driving mode > Incoming call`. See if you can find something similar on your phone.